# DAX: How to sum values between two dates from unrelated table?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have three tables,

```
Supplier
    SupplierID

SupplierRebate
    SupplierID (Is a key to Supplier[SupplierID]
    DateStart
    DateEnd
    TurnoverMin
    RebateRate

ProductBought
    SupplierID (Is a key to supplier[SupplierID]
    TotalPrice
    DateInvoice
```

ProductBought and SupplierRebate are both linked to Supplier. I am trying to make the sum of the total price, during each rebate.
I want for each rebate, for a perticular supplier, to Sum total price when the DateInvoice is between DateStart and DateEnd.

It looked so simple, and I've spent hours trying to understand, but I just can't seem to get DAX into my brain. I've tried Sum, SUMX, Filters, Calculate and a few others. I just can't seem to understand Dax.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

I think if you create a both side relationship between 
**SupplierID <-> SupplierRebate**   and
**SupplierID <-> ProductBought**  and create a single row card for Total Price with DateInvoice as Slicer , it should do the trick. DAX won't be required then.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't have the relationship going both way, so it was giving me errors everywhere. It's already helped me tremendously. The thing is, I'm not trying to create a card, but a table. I would like the table to show how much of the TotalPrice was spend during each period of a rebate.
You method (if I understand correctly) would mean that I could select a period with a slicer. I'm not trying to do that, I'm trying to know how much was spent at a supplier during the period of the rebates that are associated with him.

Comment: You will be able to create a table as well , once the relationship is changed to both side.

Answer (score 0):

The below doesn't require bidirectional relationships, which should in everything I've ever read/watched/heard about DAX should pretty much be avoided at all costs.

`SUMMARIZE (
    SupplierRebate,
    Supplier[SupplierID],
    SupplierRebate[DateStart],
    SupplierRebate[DateEnd],
    SupplierRebate[TurnoverMin],
    SupplierRebate[RebateRate],
    "Total Purchased", CALCULATE (
        SUM ( ProductBought[TotalPrice] ),
        FILTER (
            ProductBought,
            ProductBought[DateInvoice] <= MAX ( SupplierRebate[DateEnd] ) &&
            ProductBought[DateInvoice] >= MAX ( SupplierRebate[DateStart] ) 
        )
    )
)`